# Numpy matrix multiplication between a 2D array and each vector in 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have one 3 x 3 `numpy.ndarray`, i.e. H,  and one M x N x 3 `numpy.ndarray`, i.e. A.

What I want to do is multiplying H with each **vector** in A.

```
import numpy as np

H = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])  # 3 x 3 matrix

A = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]],

              [[10, 11, 12],
               [13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18]]])  # 2 x 3 x 3 matrix
```

For example, in the above code, I want to apply matrix and vector multiplication between H and `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]`, ..., `[16, 17, 18]`, which are **vector elements** of A.

Therefore, the result would be

```
np.array([[[14, 32, 50],     # H @ A[0, 0]
           [32, 77, 122],    # H @ A[0, 1]
           [50, 122, 194]],  # H @ A[0, 2]

          [[68, 167, 266],   # H @ A[1, 0]
           [86, 212, 338],   # H @ A[1, 1]
           [104, 257, 410]]] # H @ A[1, 2]
        )
```

When I broadcast `H @ A`, `H @ A[0]` and `H @ A[1]` are applied, which is not that I expected.

Is there a way to broadcast in the way I want?

Comment: `np.einsum('ij, klj -> kli', H, A)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `@` operator:

```
A @ H.T
 
array([[[ 14,  32,  50],
        [ 32,  77, 122],
        [ 50, 122, 194]],

       [[ 68, 167, 266],
        [ 86, 212, 338],
        [104, 257, 410]]])
```